# Incluir javascript de terceros en React da error Uncaught SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, script, react-hooks, mime

Estoy tratando de incluir un script en una aplicación de React, sin embargo me da un error de tipo Uncaught SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'. Ya he buscado y hay varias opciones relacionadas con cambiar el tipo MIME, pero lamentablemente parece ser que algo no estoy entendiendo porque no me funcionan.
Para incluir el javascript de forma dinámica he creado un hook con la siguiente estructura:

```
import { useEffect } from "react";

const useScript = (url) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = url;
    script.async = true;
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.onload = () => {
      console.log("estoy cargando script " + url);
    };
    document.body.appendChild(script);
    return () => {
      document.body.removeChild(script);
    };
  }, [url]);
};

export default useScript;
```

En este caso a manera de prueba creo un archivo .js que debe mostrarme un mensaje por consola. El archivo solo tiene la siguientes líneas de código

`console.log("Estoy leyendo archivo");`

Mi app principal tiene la siguiente estructura:

```
import React from "react";

import useScript from "./hooks/useScript";

export default function App() {
  useScript("public/assets/pruebas/test.js");
  return (
    <div>
      Hola mundo
    </div>
  );
}
```

La primera parte funciona porque por la consola veo el mensaje  de confirmación, de que sí, se está cargando el script, pero nunca veo se está leyendo el script.
Esta es la imagen de la consola:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

También me doy cuenta de que en las peticiones se recibe el fichero javascript como si fuera html
[image: Señalo la fila en color rojo]

Muchas gracias de antemano

Comment: ¿Estás usando `create-react-app`? Saludos

Comment: Te falta cerrar el div donde muestras "Hola mundo"

Comment: Si estoy utilizando `create-react-app`. Y si, tambien hay un error en la transcripción del código. Lo arreglo enseguida, pero no afecta la situación inicial. Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intenta modificando la `url`, ambas formas en el siguiente ejemplo funcionan, pero usar la variable global `process.env.PUBLIC_URL` es [recomendado](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-the-public-folder/) :

```
function App() {
  //useScript("assets/pruebas/test.js");
  useScript(process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "assets/pruebas/test.js");
  return (
    <div>
      Hola mundo
    </div>
  );
}
```

Parece ser que estás experimentando, sería bueno revisar [esta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44114436/the-create-react-app-imports-restriction-outside-of-src-directory) publicación, puede haber implicaciones con el bundle, al usar archivos que esten fuera del folder `src`.

Espero que esta respuesta sea de ayuda.

Comment: Muchas gracias, me funciona de esa manera.

Comment: @ragolo, me parece interesante como estas comunicándote con el archivo JS, si consideras que la respuesta fue de utilidad, no olvides votar y aceptarla,  esto ayuda a que otros usuarios puedan usar esta información como referencia, saludos.