# Problema convertir componentDidMount() a useEffect()

Tags: reactjs

Hola quisiera llevar este codigo de componentDidMount() a useEffect() sobre todo en la parte de script.onload = () => this.scriptLoaded();

```
componentDidMount() {
    const script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = "/static/libs/your_script.js";
    script.async = true;
    script.onload = () => this.scriptLoaded();

    document.body.appendChild(script);
}
```

Comment: Creo que [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/426381/incluir-javascript-de-terceros-en-react-da-error-uncaught-syntaxerror-expected/426595#426595) te puede ayudar, se esta cargando un script desde el folder `public` con `useEffect`, muy parecido a lo que estas buscando lograr, considera votar por la misma si fue de utilidad, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

¿Cuál es la función `scriptLoaded()`?

Creo que es solo quitar el `this` y nada mas.

```
useEffect( () => {
   const script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = "/static/libs/your_script.js";
    script.async = true;
    script.onload = () => scriptLoaded();

    document.body.appendChild(script); }, [])
```