# hay alguna forma de tomar un archivo de la carpeta public de react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

me gustaria poder tomar un archivo json de la carpeta public de react algo como:

```
const archivo = require('../public/archivo.json');
```

se puede hacer eso?

Comment: prueba hacerlo obeiendo el archivo mediante el protocolo de http

Comment: cómo? otra solución seria lograr responder esta pregunta https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/465734/c%c3%b3mo-hago-que-react-no-comprima-un-archivo-cuando-uso-npm-run-build o lograr lo que se muestra en este articulo: https://www.it-swarm-es.com/es/javascript/obtener-el-archivo-json-local-de-la-carpeta-publica-reactjs/833994830/ pero no puedo

Comment: [Aquí un ejemplo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/426381/incluir-javascript-de-terceros-en-react-da-error-uncaught-syntaxerror-expected/426595#426595) de comunicación con la carpeta public, con custom hook y variable global, pero solo si estas usando create-react-app.

Comment: gracias por tu ayuda pero lo solucione usando local storage porque no me dejaba traer un json y mantenerlo