# ¿Error en el import cuando se utiliza el lazy en react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-hooks

Estoy tratando de crear un componente que permita utilizar file.svg en react native con **react-native-svg-transform**, cuando el path en el import está de manera estica funciona bien, el problema es cuando le asigno una variable para que sea dinámico, el import no reconoce esa variable  y arroja el el siguiente error.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es el código hecho en TypeScript

```
import { View } from 'react-native';
import React, { Suspense} from 'react';

interface Props {
    name: string,
    path: string
}
export const ImageSvg = (props: Props) => {

    const Component = React.lazy(() => import('../assets/'+props.name+'.svg'));

     return (
         <View>
             <Suspense fallback={null}>
                 <Component/>
             </Suspense>
         </View>
     )
}
```

Comment: El `import` de `lazy` debería ser para un componente que tenga un elemento `img` para mostrar la imagen`svg`, pero aquí estas tratando de importar la imagen svg como un si fuera un componente. No estoy seguro de esto, ya que no veo un ejemplo parecido en la [doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#reactlazy)

Comment: Estoy utilizando react-native-svg-trasnform, con en ello me permite usar SVG como un componente, el problema es que la ruta tiene que ser estática para que se pueda renderizar, si hay una ruta dinámica no funciona

Comment: Bien, puse ese dato en la pregunta. ¿Y que tal si pones tu carpeta assets en el folder public? Por ejemplo con el template create-react-app se puede hacer uso de variables globales para comunicarse con el [path public](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/426381/incluir-javascript-de-terceros-en-react-da-error-uncaught-syntaxerror-expected/426595#426595) y parece ser estático. Saludos