# Llamar a un archivo js desde html

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Estoy teniendo problemas para modularizar mi código. Estoy trabajando con React JS.
En mi proyecto tengo la siguiente estructura de archivos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Yo desde mi componente Home necesito llamar al archivo graph.js que contiene un grafico realizado en JavaScript, lo estoy haciendo de esta manera:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../graphs/graph.js"></script>
```

Este método no me está funcionando, no se cual será la manera correcta. Agradezco su ayuda

Comment: ponle <script defer="defer" type="text/javascript" src="../graphs/graph.js"></script>

Comment: Tampoco me lo renderiza de esa manera. Debería agregar algo extra en el archivo js? Algo asi como una exportación?

Comment: Puede que [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/426595/101408) sea de ayuda, si lo fue no olvides darle un voto

Comment: Podrias poner lo siguiente: `<script type="module" src="../graphs/graph.js"></script>` y podrias intentar exportar una funcion que tengas en **graph.js**

Comment: Como puedo exportar una funcion que tenga en graph.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esa no es la forma adecuada de importar un componente en react.js.

*Lo que debes hacer es importar tu componente.*

```
import { Graph } from ../graphs/graph.js
```

*y luego dentro de tu componente padre agregarlo de la siguiente forma:*

```
<Graph/>
```

**Esto va funcionar si en tu archivo `graph.js` creaste tu componente con function o const y luego hiciste el export correspondiente.**

Espero te sirva mi ayuda, avísame si te funciona!